# How to fully preload a React site with SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preload, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to have a preloader for a small site I've made using React. I'm expecting the preloader to preload all the assets such as images, fonts and JS files including that bundle.js itself.

My intention is for the user to see the preloader when he first enters the site as the assets are being loaded. Once the site is fully loaded, the actual site will then show up. Think of the kind of preloaders we used to see in those old-school Flash sites.

However, I'm not sure how I should do this. One of the methods I've tried is using `import()` in the entry component which loads the actual main component containing the content. Something like this in the entry component:

```
const load = () => import('./MainSite')
load().then((comp) => {
  //render comp in render()
})
```

While this does split the `MainSite.js`, which has the main content and links to all the other site, into a separate chunk, I still face 3 problems with this method:

1. The main `bundle.js` is still 600kb while the `0.chunk.js` of that
   MainSite.js is only 100kb. This only preloads the 100kb. The user still has to wait for the 600kb to load when entering the site.
2. This method also messes up SSR. All content in `MainSite.js` is
       not rendered at the server. So there is no SSR.
3. This only preloads the JS chunk file. The images, fonts, CSS, etc
   are not preloaded.

What would be a better approach to *fully* preload a React site while avoiding the 3 problems?

Comment: Things were very different in Flash. Assets and their sizes were known beforehand. They usually aren't in JS app. You would need to pack all assets to JS to take full controls of them, this wouldn't be very efficient. I doubt that 600kb file (the number is less with gzip) needs progress bar. You will have hard time calculating progress bar for anything but JS. Depending on your case, you could probably benefit from PWA, service worker could possibly make it easier to calculate progress bar for assets as well. PWA doesn't necessary need SSR, but you can search for 'pwa ssr' for some ideas.

Comment: @estus  I have come across sites, particularly microsites, that are seemingly having such preloaders. For eg, godofwar.playstation.com. Granted, they are not using React, but I was wondering whether the technique they use could be ported over to a React site.

Comment: I already mentioned the approaches that can be used. You need to know the list of loaded resources and possibly their sizes to track the progress in %. You either pack binary files to JS and track the progress of the bundle, this provides a lot of overhead due to encoding. Or track them otherwise, e.g. by communicating with service worker. I checked GOW website, and it sucks at this, progress bar appears lately after the website was mostly loaded and tracks only several big images, I suppose the list of images was hard-coded.